# Is there a way to remove an item from multiple lists that got entered simultaniously?

Tags: c#, list

So I'm making a program with 6 text boxes, 3 for input and 3 to review your input. This is my first real project, still a student.

Input boxes: txtInvUID, txtInvDescriptionButton and txtInvArduinoContact
Review: txtUID, txtDescriptionButton and txtArduinoContact

Whenever you enter something wrong you have the option to delete it via another textbox (you enter the UID here)

This works *however* it just moves up the list, the UID's get moved up and the DescriptionButton and ArduinoContact things remain in place. Is there any way for me to remove the ArduinoContact and DescriptionButton linked to this UID? All 3 inputs have been put in a different list named UID, DESCRBUTTON and ARDUINOCONTACT.

***code:***

```
else
{
    UID.Add(Convert.ToInt16(txtInvUID.Text));
    DESCRBUTTON.Add(txtInvDescriptionButton.Text);
    ARDUINOCONTACT.Add(Convert.ToInt16(txtInvArduinoContact.Text));

    txtUID.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, UID);
    txtDescriptionButton.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, DESCRBUTTON);
    txtArduinoContact.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, ARDUINOCONTACT);

    txtInvUID.Text = string.Empty;
    txtInvDescriptionButton.Text = string.Empty;
    txtInvArduinoContact.Text = string.Empty;

}
```

```
private void btnVerwijder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UID.Remove(Convert.ToInt32(txtVerwijderen.Text));
}
```

Comment: There's good news, and there's bad news. The good news is that there's a name for this pattern. The bad news is that it's generally considered an anti-pattern (i.e. something to avoid). One name for it is [Parallel Collections](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/) You should instead be thinking about creating a class that has UID, Description and Contact properties and storing instances of that class in *one* list.

Comment: So putting it into one list it is, but, how would I go about splitting it into 3 different textboxes so that I receive the same idea I have now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the index to locate the item in each list.

```
var list1 = new List<string>() { "a1", "a2", "a3" };
var list2 = new List<string>() { "b1", "b2", "b3" }; 
var list3 = new List<string>() { "c1", "c2", "c3" };

var itemToBeRemoved = "a2";

var indexOfItem = list1.IndexOf(itemToBeRemoved);
list1.RemoveAt(indexOfItem);
list2.RemoveAt(indexOfItem);
list3.RemoveAt(indexOfItem);
```